# Implements a abstract method with interface type hint with a concrete typing class

Tags: php

Here a simple question that I can't explain.

In the PHP manual:

> If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too.

I keep in mind that it's the case of an abstract method, but it seems to me like "no logic".

Here is an example:

I search how to implement a method(in this example, invoke) by this way:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bundle\BarBundle;

abstract class BaseClass {

    //...

    abstract public function invoke(AddContactCommandInterface $command);
}

<?php
namespace Foo\Bundle\UpBarBundle;

use Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\BaseClass;

class UpClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function invoke(AddContactCommand $command)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**AddContactCommand implements AddContactCommandInterface !**

I've got this issue

> Declaration must be compatible with BaseClass->invoke(AddContactCommandInterface)

Somebody could explain to me why it's not possible to do this basic and logical manipulation in `PHP 5.6` ?

Answer (score 2):

The abstract method defines a function that all the derived classes need to implement.  In defining the abstract method you said it takes a `AddContactCommandInterface` and then in your child class change it to `AddContactCommand`.  You are changing the "contract" that was specified in the Abstract class.

It doesn't matter that `AddContactCommand` implements the interface.  Not all `AddContactCommandInterfaces` are `AddContactCommands`.

From a usage point of view, if this were allowed it would cause difficulty because I could have a method that expects to use a `BaseClass` object.  And I have a different object `Foo` that implements `AddContactCommandInterface`.  Now my method gets an instance of `UpClass` and tries to use the `invoke` method passing in my `Foo` object.  This will result in a Fatal Error even though from my understanding of the contract specified in the Abstract class, I should have been able to use my `Foo` object.  Confusion and mass hysteria ensue.

This isn't a problem of logic but of consistency.  If you actually want to type hint `AddContactCommand` change the abstract method.  But if you are intending that all things that implement `AddContactCommandInterface` can be used then change the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

`BaseClass` states that any child class must have a public method named invoke that accepts any object that implements `AddContactCommandInterface`.

`UpClass` does not fullfil this requirement.
Its invoke function only accepts a concrete instance of `AddContactCommand` or child objects.

Should your code be allowed, the following would fail:

```
class SomeOther implements AddContactCommandInterface
{
    //implementation of interface
}

$up = new UpClass();
$up->invoke(new SomeOther());
```

Why not just have `UpClass->invoke` accept an implementation of the inteface? You can still pass in a concrete `AddContactCommand`

Comment: Thanks all of you for your quick responses ! The problem is that i want to write first a abstract bundle and then have unlimited numbers of childs bundles around. (in my work, a do something like, HumanBundle, man and woman bundles). The business logic must have to be centralizing inside our AbstractBundle. So, the hint type for invokes methods should not be the same for, our example, man or womanBundles, but they have in common the famous CommandInterface, the only solution i have is to not reference the invoke methods (or others "precisions" methods) into my AbtractBundles. too bad !

Comment: You may want to rethink your design as your `AbstractBundle` is kind of a god-class and will likely limit some of the flexibility in your design in the future.  The fact that it has the name "AbstractBundle" is a code smell to me as it gives me no clue as to what this classes responsibilities are.

Answer (score 0):

In your second class, you are overriding the BaseClass;s `invoke` method ---

This requires that the `invoke` method in your child class accepts the same argument -

In this case, you have type-hinted that the argumen, `$command` is of type `AddContactCommandInterface` --- but, in your child class, you made the argument `AddContactCommand`

Thus, you can fix it by making the `$command` in your base class the same type as the `$command` in your child class -- or, vice versa.